# Copying pose of one leg to another withouot using x- axis mirroring

Tags: animation, rigging

I have a 3 legged character and I want to copy the pose of one leg to another. Shift Ctrl V doesn't work tho because that only works when I want to mirror along the x-axis but my character has 3 legs so that isn't possible. Is there anyway I can do that?

For example I have this pose

[image]

And when I copy then Shift Ctrl V it simply moves the same bone in a different spot. Instead of having the same pose on the other leg.
[image]

Comment: maybe show some pictures, or even share your file, what does it give if you simply copy paste?

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: Could we also see the bone hierarchy.  If leg is parented such that locally each  transform is same can simply copy prop or  use copy constraints to match pose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's another way to do it than this one:

- First make sure that the axis of your second bone is good:

[image]

- Create the animation for your first bone. Select the keyframes in the *Dopesheet* and copy, make sure to have the *Only Selected* (little arrow icon) option enabled:

[image]
[image]

- Select the second bone, in the Dopesheet create a keyframe on its rest position (this step seems necessary):

[image]

- Now paste in the *DopeSheet*, it creates new keyframe(s), the second bone has now the same animation as the first one:

[image]